# Quartz scheduler instance is null

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, vaadin, quartz

I developed an application using vaadin and quartz scheduler. I have this code :

```
final ServletContext servletContext = VaadinServlet.getCurrent().getServletContext();

StdSchedulerFactory stdSchedulerFactory = (StdSchedulerFactory) servletContext
            .getAttribute(QuartzInitializerListener.QUARTZ_FACTORY_KEY);
final Scheduler scheduler = stdSchedulerFactory.getScheduler();
```

So I notice that sometimes after the server reboot I have a `java.lang.NullPointerException`  on this line `stdSchedulerFactory.getScheduler()`

Can you explain me what happen?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the way you *initialize the scheduler*.
I think someone had a similar problem (different error, but same usage).

```
//Create & start the scheduler.
        StdSchedulerFactory factory = new StdSchedulerFactory();
        factory.initialize(servletContext.getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/my_quartz.properties"));
        scheduler = factory.getScheduler();
```

Please take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10316768/3434672) for more details.